# Ziping files with python. Windows cant unzip

Tags: python, zip

I have this ziping script in python :

```
 def zipdir(self,path, ziph):
        # ziph is zipfile handle
        paths = os.listdir(path)
        for p in paths:
            p = os.path.join(path, p)  # Make the path relative
            if os.path.isfile(p):  # Recursive case
                ziph.write(p)  # Write the file to the zipfile



    #needs to be closed after use
    def createZipHandler(self,name):
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(name+'.zip', 'w')
        return zipf
```

The Plan is to call this class and create a zip which should be opened on windows maschines. When running this script on windows everything work fine. zip created and accessable. 
But when calling this in my code on a raspberry I cant open the zip on my windows maschine.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: any error? Does opening it from python work?

Comment: dont tried to open with python. When unziping with 7zip on windows it returns : "Headers error ,Unconfirmed state of archive , there are some data after the end of the payload" /absolutePath/myfile.extension may be currupted

Comment: When unziping it creates me entire path again. e.g /home/bin/cwd/home/bin/cwd/fileWhichWasZiped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem. The zipping went fine. I send the zip over email and set a wrong header-element.